# CentOS-Like configuration of Vim on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, centos, centos6, vim

Whenever I use a CentOS System, there's always a pleasant configuration of vim which mainly does the following:

- Remembering position of closed files
- Colour mode (!!!)
- Bash has colours

There's lots more, just not something i can recall on the spot.

Then, i go to ubuntu and its all black and white, no nice vim config etc. I have to use Ubuntu, and I hate ubuntu because of this.

I know I can all configure it by myself, so my question is: **How can I configure the Ubuntu system to behave (aesthetically) like CentOS?**

PS to future self: I will be stoned to death for asking such a question.

Comment: Two probable causes: a) in Ubuntu you are using `vi` or `vim-minimal`, not `vim-enhanced`; b) you have to tweak 1. the default `vimrc` for system-wide configuration 2. `~/.vimrc` for your personal use. This question fits better in the SuperUser or Unix&Linux sites.

Comment: @dawud i have vim/vim-enhanced.

Comment: Then, b). There are literally tons of enhancements, plugins, themes and whatnot to improve your user experience in `vim`. You can just copy-paste your config from the CentOS box.